# Sorting a text box in continuous form using a command button

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm building a form in continuous form format, and I want to add a button that sorts a specific text box in ascending, and when I click again in descending.

I've tried to do the following code but it doesn't seem to focus on a specific text box.

```
Private Sub cmdSort_Click()
    Me.OrderBy = Me!lblTaTtxt.tag
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortDescending
    Me.OrderByOn = True
End Sub
```

I expected it to focus on the text box connected to "lblTaTtxt" and to sort the text box, but it sorts a different box in the form. Would appreciate some clarification, as I am very new  to Access

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on the label `lblTaTtxt` it will sort the connected textbox

```
Private Sub lblTaTtxt_Click()

    Dim strDirection As String
    strDirection = Me.OrderBy

    If strDirection Like "* DESC" Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortAscending
    Else
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortDescending
    End If
    Me.OrderByOn = True

End Sub
```